# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar datos con el subObjeto referenciado en moogose?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, mongodb, mongoose

Soy nuevo en mongo, lo que quiero hacer es filtrar los productos por el nombre de la marca, no quiero hacerlo por su _id o "code_brand", de tal manera que me muestre solo los productos que contengan la marca seleccionada o escrita y excluya las productos que no contengan esa marca, he intentado hacerlo de esta manera:

```
const documents = await this.model
        .find({ brand: { name: "adidas" } })
```

Y esto:

```
  const documents = await this.model
        .find({ "brand.name":"adidas" })
```

Pero no muestra ningún cambio, este es mi código, donde las categorías, subcategorías y marcas son objetos referenciados por el `.populate()`:

```
 const documents = await this.model
        .find({ brand: { name: "adidas" } })
        .limit(limit)
        .skip(offset)
        .select(" -status -__v ")
        .populate([
          {
            path: "brand",
            select: " -status -__v -_id",
            match: { status: true },
          },
          {
            path: "category",
            select: " -status -__v -_id",
            match: { status: true },
          },
          {
            path: "subCategory",
            select: " -status -__v -_id",
            match: { status: true },
          },
        ])
        .sort(order);
```

Esto es lo tengo de resultado que obtengo (ojo lo subí en este enlace, ya intentar publicarlo stackoverflow me dice que mucho código): https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/y2368b97d

MODELO DE PRODUCT :

```
import { Schema, model, Types } from "mongoose";

const schema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    code_brand: { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    image: { type: String, required: false },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    code_categories: { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    code_subCategories: { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    status: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  },
  {
    collection: "products",

    timestamps: {
      createdAt: "created_at",
      updatedAt: "updated_at",
    },
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true,
    },
  }
);

schema.virtual("brand", {
  ref: "brands",
  localField: "code_brand",
  foreignField: "_id",
  justOne: true,
});

schema.virtual("category", {
  ref: "categories",
  localField: "code_categories",
  foreignField: "_id",
  justOne: true,
});

schema.virtual("subCategory", {
  ref: "subCategories",
  localField: "code_subCategories",
  foreignField: "_id",
  justOne: true,
});


const products = model("products", schema);

export default products;
```

Comment: El `populate` se ejecuta luego de realizar la consulta, por lo tanto `brand` no tendrá ninguna propiedad cuando ejecutes el `find`. Lo que debes hacer es usar `aggregate` con `$lookup` para hacer un match entre ambas colecciones, y luego si usar $match para filtrar esa coleccion combinada. (Lo anterior suponiendo que la propiedad `brand` del modelo actual contiene el `_id` de un documento de la coleccion `brand`)

Comment: Podrias agregar el modelo de `this.model` para saber exactamente como ayudarte?

Comment: OK entoces , lo tendria que hacerlo por aggregate, ya agrege el modelo